# Does World of Warcraft Legions purchase include gametime and base game?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I ordered World of Warcraft Legion expansion online as a physical CD, and I was wondering if that included the base game or do I have to have the base game first in order to use this expansion pack CD? Also, if I don't have to buy the base game first do I get a 30 day game time with this?

[image: This is what I ordered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to buy the base game first which automatically comes with 30 days of game time.

Comment: So I can get the base game as a physical cd and then get the legions expansions as a cd and download them both right?

Comment: Correct. You can simply buy them online as a digital download as they will need to download a lot of data for you to be able to play anyway. There is no real point to buying a physical copy of an online game, because online games will always need to download updates therefore rendering the use of a CD meaningless. In the future for instance, the game could potentially use none of the data on the CD at all, meaning you will have to download a large update.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Also all the previous expansions are part of the base game but legion isn't right?

Comment: Correct. Based on previous releases, Legion may become part of the base game at the release of the next expansion. Also if you have more questions I suggest asking them as a separate question, as I don't think the website is designed for multiple unrelated questions tacked onto a different question.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have 3 options when you start playing WoW, but if you already have Legion it is recommended to get the base game right away as the expansion requires it. The base game then comes with 30 days of free game time. Having Legion when starting the WoW adventure has some serious benefits, such as not needing to level your first character through all previous expansions and of course access to the new class trial.

*Free Starter:*

- No costs
- Do whatever you want **up to level 20**
- You can NOT trade, join guilds or use the global chat (trade)
- You can NOT use races or classes restricted to expansions not included in the base game (right now: Legion -> Demon Hunter)
- You can NOT access content of expansions not included (Legion content starts with Level 98, so it's pretty hard anyway)

*Base Game:*

- Comes with 30 days of game time
- Requires paid subscription after the free time has expired
- You can do anything **up to Level 100** (Warlords of Draenor)
- Includes all previous expansions

  - The Burning Crusade
  - Wrath of the Lich King
  - Cataclysm
  - Mists of Pandaria
  - Warlords of Draenor
- You can NOT use classes restricted to Legion (Demon Hunter)
- You can NOT access Legion content

*Latest expansion (Legion):*

- You can do anything **up to Level 110**
- Requires the base game and a paid subscription
- Includes a **free character boost** to Level 100, so you can start playing Legion right away
- **Class trial!** Try any class on Level 100 and decide later which one you want to play. You can as well apply your free boost on one of these. Very handy, if you don't know what class you want to play.